# "... has never been awaited" Error (Discord-Bot, Python)

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

```
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)
  while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    
      
async def job():
  print("I'm working...")
  channel = client.get_channel(651895929426673704)
  await channel.send('hello')
```

With that I am getting the error "coroutine 'job' was never awaited self._run_job(job)" but wherever I add it than I always get "object function can't be used in 'await' expression" can someone please tell me what I did wrong or where I have to put it?

Comment: It doesn't look like `schedule` is an asyncio library

Comment: @Grismar nope, it's from https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` this will stop your whole code. Use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` to only sleep that function. Plus look at the [`discord.ext.tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could read "schedule" module does not support Asynchronous tasks. You can try using [aioschedule](https://github.com/ibrb/python-aioschedule), which is forked off the repository of dbader. Works the same way, just for `async` functions.

Another option is built in the discord API already, using [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html).

```py
from discord.ext import tasks
...

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    job.start() # To start the loop when your bot starts

@task.loop(seconds=5)
async def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    channel = client.get_channel(651895929426673704)
    await channel.send('hello')


# You can also add commands to start and stop the task loop
@client.command()
async def job_start(ctx):
    job.start()

@client.command()
async def job_stop(ctx):
    job.stop()
```

Example for scheduling task for every day at given time, using `aioschedule`

```py
import aioschedule as schedule
...

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(job) # "job" is scheduled for 8pm every day
  while True:
    await schedule.run_pending()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def job():
  print("I'm working...")
  channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
  await channel.send('hello')
```

Comment: @LordofDarkness If you don't specify any timezone, it will use local time. Make sure you use 24h time, not 12h time. I tested it just now and it works fine. editing my answer to show for `schedule.every().day.at("time").do(job)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anything like this:

```
import asyncio
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)
  while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    
      
async def job2():
  print("I'm working...")
  channel = client.get_channel(651895929426673704)
  await channel.send('hello')
def job():
    asyncio.gather(job)
```